# /proc/cpuinfo gives CPU info per core or per thread?

Tags: linux, cpu, multi-core, hyper-threading

My CPU has 2 cores, so I can see two parts in `/proc/cpuinfo`.

But, I want to know if CPUs that support Hyper-Threading (or similar tech), will `/proc/cpuinfo` give CPU info per core or per thread (or call it sibling)?

I only know that Windows Task Manager will give CPU usage statistics per thread if the CPU supports HT.

Comment: Also there's no /etc/cpuinfo.

Answer (score 8):

The contents of `/proc/cpuinfo` contains information for all processors down to the virtual level.

Here are some tips on interpreting the contents:

- Each physical processor will present as at least one processor
- Each core will present as at least one processor
- Each hyperthread will present as one processor.

Thus, a dual-socket, dual-core, hyperthreaded system will show as 8 processors. A similar quad-core system will show as 16 processors.

Within the content of `/proc/cpuinfo` each logical processor has its own ID. If your system is SMP then it will also have a `physical id`. This is naturally the physical processor number. If you have a multi-core processor then each logical processor will also have a `core id`. Core ID's are only unique within a single processor. I.e, physical 0 will have core 0 and core 1, and physical 1 will also have core 0 and core 1.

Answer (score 3):

Hyper Threading would appear in /proc/cpuinfo as separate processors.  So if your CPU have 2 cores each with hyper-threading enabled then /proc/cpuinfo would show 4 processors.

Hence as you describe your configuration, hyper-threading is either not available, or it is not enabled in the bios.